# Загрузка картинок с предпросмотром

Tags: java, ajax, spring

Здравствуйте. Интересует следующий вопрос. Каким образом с помощью java, spring, jsp, js, jquery реализовать загрузку и предпросмотр картинок?
На данный момент я реализовал это дело с помощью html5  fileapi, вот только возникает проблема. Превью изображений работает как нужно, но если вдруг другие поля формы заполнены неверно и срабатывает информирование об ошибках, превью картинок пропадает.  Собственно задача состоит в том, чтобы превью было постоянным даже в вышеуказанном случае.
    Интересует прежде всего механизм реализации и необходимые средства. Возможно кто-то поделится полезными ссылками на код.

Фрагмент разметки из JSP:

```
<li class="photo_li">
    <label class="input_label">
     Добавьте фото:
    </label>
    <div id="photo_div">
        <c:forEach var="v" varStatus="vs" items="${multiFileBucket.files}">
              <span class="photo">
                   <label class="label_for_photo">
                        <form:input type="file" path="files[${vs.index}].file" id="files[${vs.index}].file"/>
                        <span class="label_for_image_preview"></span>
                              <div class="has-error">
                                 <form:errors path="files[${vs.index}].file" class="error_label"/>
                              </div>
                   </label>
              </span>
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
</li>
```

Функция JS по выводу превью:

```
function handleFileSelectSingle(evt, text) {

var file = evt.target.files; // FileList object
var f = file[0]

// Only process image files.
if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
    alert("Только изображения....");
    return;
}
else {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    // Closure to capture the file information.
    reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
        return function (e) {
            // Render thumbnail.
            var span = document.createElement('span');
            span.innerHTML = ['<img class="label_for_image_preview" src="', e.target.result,
                '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');

            text.querySelector("span").innerHTML = "";
            text.querySelector("span").insertBefore(span, null);
        };
    })(f);
    // Read in the image file as a data URL.
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
}
}
```

Контроллер, обрабатывающий форму

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
public String add(@Valid MultiFileBucket multiFileBucket, @Valid @ModelAttribute("addapplicationdto") AddApplicationDTO appl, BindingResult result) throws IOException {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "add_zayavka";
    } else {
        int fileNumber = 1;
        for (FileBucket bucket : multiFileBucket.getFiles()) {
            if (bucket.getFile().getSize() == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            else {
                FileCopyUtils.copy(bucket.getFile().getBytes(), new File(UPLOAD_LOCATION + fileNumber+".jpg"));
                fileNumber++;
            }
        }
        return "zayavka_podana";
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код.

Comment: выложил фрагменты кода

Answer (score 3):

Нет надобности в загрузке картинки сразу. Когда вы вставляете картинку в превью, в атрибуте `src` вашего `img`. записывается картинка в виде `base64`. Можно когда человек выбирает картинку записывать в `localStorage` ну или куки. И если возникнет ошибка то взять данные оттуда и подставить. А саму загрузку файла выполнять при успешной проверке данных формы.

Ещё как вариант разделить всё на два запроса (знаю что не очень, но мороки меньше). Сначала проверить форму и записать данные и ответ от сервера положительный выполнить загрузку картинки.

Comment: Хм, с про куки и local storage почитаю, спасибо

Comment: Сделал как Вы рекомендовали, возникло 2 вопроса. Первый: у меня загружается 6 картинок, они в 5 мб localStorage врядле влезут в виде base64. Есть ли альтернативы? Второй: после выгрузки картинки из localStorage, превью работает, а на сервер картинка не уходит.